# What is an "exception handler state"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, compiler-errors, try-catch

[Visual Studio's error C1509](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1509) says:

> too many exception handler states in function

I'm curious as to exactly what an "exception handler state" is. It claims that the max number of states is: *2<sup>15</sup>*. However when I do not get this error when I run the file generated by this code, which has *2<sup>15</sup> + 1* `try`-`catch` blocks:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream foo{ "main.cpp" };
  const auto primer = "\tfoo = value(g);\n";

  const auto body = "\ttry{\n"
                    "\t\tcout << 13.0F / foo << endl;\n"
                    "\t}catch(...){\n"
                    "\t\tcout << \"error\\n\";\n"
                    "\t}\n";

  const auto count = (1 << 15) + 1;

  if(foo)
  {
    foo <<  "#include <iostream>\n"
            "#include <random>\n"
            "\n"
            "using namespace std;\n"
            "\nint main(){\n"
            "\tmt19937 g{ random_device()() };\n"
            "\tuniform_int_distribution<> value{ 0, 13 };\n"
            "\tauto foo = value(g);\n"
            "\n" 
        << body;

    for(auto i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
      foo << endl << primer << body;
    }
    foo << '}' << endl;
  }
}
```

**So what is an exception handler state?**

Comment: I suspect that the error message is related to try/catch, because the link is saying: "... The most common cause is that the function contains a complex expression of user-defined class variables and arithmetic operators. "

Comment: @deepmax Yeah, I had generated some code that tripped the error, so now I was trying to make a minimal example which also tripped the error... But even with 32,769 `try`-`catch` blocks I don't see the error. Maybe the compiler is optimizing out my blocks?

Comment: Is it this code you are showing that generates the error?  I cannot reproduce your error with this code on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/bKvHZW) or my local machine

Comment: I once generated C++ code which consisted of (really) many nested constructor calls. (I would never write such code manually but as I said - it was generated.) Compiling the release in VS needed minutes (for one translation unit) but I didn't care so much. At some point in development I got finally an error which I believe was that or similar. Unfortunately, it's some years ago and I don't remember clearly... :-( (I modified the code generation (reducing nesting of calls) to fix this and problem was gone.)

Comment: I don't see reason to generate such code, when template can do it directly in result code. Anyway just correct generation in such way that one function one try, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver nono, the code that trips this is a bunch of auto generated stuff. The code I have shown here *generates a file* that I was attempting to use in the recreation of this error, because I didn't understand if an "exception handler state" was in fact a `try`-`catch` block. The file this code generates is 229,393 lines long so I can't attach it :(

Comment: can you explain why do you have to use generator? And why you want to catch errors in such early stage?

Comment: @MarekR So the process of generating this code is very complex (read fragile.) I just need to know *exactly* what my goal is before I set out rewriting it. Thus I wanted to make a toy example that would trip this error, and figure out how to fix the toy example, before trying to apply the same fix to the generation process.

Comment: @JonathanMee I see.  AFAIK a handler is the catch block so to many exception handler states to me sounds like you would have to have 2^15 different types of things you catch.

Comment: @MarekR The generator converts from xml inputted by a user into an actual .cpp file that is pulled in by my build process. Catching an error as precisely as possible is essential to providing accurate feedback on the .xml file.

Comment: Just an idea: In my case, I even didn't use `try catch` but the constructors might probably had `throw`s. (I relied on the fact that the code would either run or throw in debugging as well because the reasons for `throw` would have meant ill written code.) In my case, the nesting was not the only uglyness. Additionally, I used templates with upto 256 arguments. When I rewrote the code I had to replace both. So, I never found out which of the both facts was the actual problem for VS. (I must admit I didn't investigate - just wanted to get a release.)

Comment: @NathanOliver That does seem insightful, and probably accurate. Can you think of a way I could change my toy example to validate :/

Comment: @JonathanMee Easiest way I think would be to generate a struct for each catch block.  The you could have 2^15 unique handlers.

Comment: @NathanOliver You think that just adding the generation of an anonymous struct into the catch block should work? Something like: `cout << "error" << struct{ int mem }{ 13 }.mem << endl;`

Comment: No, I think you need to make a named struct for each catch block so that each catch block can take that struct as its parameter so you get 2^15 unique handlers.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh man that's more complex... I'll have a look at it...

Comment: @NathanOliver Will differently named structs be enough? Or do I need the contents of the structs to be different? I'm just trying to think if I can use a templatized class to do this...

Comment: I would think you just need different names structures.  This way the parameter type of the catch blocks are different.

Comment: @NathanOliver This should have worked, right: https://ideone.com/nr2t9v Templatized objects should represent different objects, should they not?